# Onclick of a Ajax.ActionLink I need to call a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a **Ajax.ActionLink()** which is as below. Onclick of which a partial view should load within the parent view. It is working fine. Now in order to give some other functionality it is required to call a javascript function on click of that **Ajax.ActionLink()**. I am not sure whether it is possible or not. I have two button **btnSubmit** and **btnUpdate**. Simply, I want to toggle "enable/disable" functionality through that Javascript function and nothing else.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.profilename, "_CreateProfile", new { profileid = item.profileid }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv" })
```

Need help...Any advice is welcome !!

Thanks!!

Comment: Try adding `OnBegin = "yourJSfunction"` attribute to AjaxOptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overloads of the `Ajax.ActionLink` contain a parameter for additional `htmlAttributes` to be rendered:

```
Ajax.ActionLink(string linkText,
                string action,
                object routeValues,
                AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
                object htmlAttributes )
```

You can define a click handler in the `htmlAttributes`:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(item.profilename, 
                 "_CreateProfile", 
                 new { profileid = item.profileid }, 
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "partialDiv" },
                 new { onclick = "handler" })
```